# Tutorial for getting data from SAP/Sybase with phonegap

Tags: cordova, sybase

I'm trying to learn about phonegap and SAP/Sybase integration. I've been searching all over to find some tutorials explaining how to retrieve some tables of simple data from sap using phonegap.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you're building a web application, you should be able to use any javascript library to connect to SAP using web services or RFC.